# Setting a batch of parents/sibblings in one call

Tags: google-apps-script, smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-1.1

I'm building an Google Script that automatically writes a Google Spreadsheet to Smartsheet, but with the parents/sibbling already formated, no need for manual indeting, since I already have to do this in the Spreadsheet, trough a numbered column.

I managed to write to the Smartsheet, but I can't seem to figure out how to send a batch (600+) of lines with parents/sibblings set, which are in the same urlFetch call.

Some questions which should solve my problem:

Is it possible to determine/specify the "rowId" that I'm about to include?

Is it possible to set "parentRowNumber" when providing the row?

Is it possible any other way to batch insert rows with parents without knowing the "rowId"?

Since I haven't found [google-apps-script] + [smartsheet-api] here yet, here's how to insert a row (working code):

```
function adcionarLinhaSmartSheet(){
  //Static for testing
  var rows = [];
  rows[0] = {};
  rows[0].cells = [];
  rows[0].cells[0] = {};
  rows[0].cells[0].columnId = "[ROW_ID]";
  rows[0].cells[0].value = 14;
  rows[0].cells[0].strict = false;

  var payload = {"toBottom":true, "rows":rows};

  var dadosEnviar = {headers:{Authorization:"Bearer [ACCESS_TOKEN]", "content-type":"application/json"}, "Method":"post", "payload":JSON.stringify(payload)};

  var planilhaSmart = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.smartsheet.com/1.1/sheet/[SHEET_ID]/rows", dadosEnviar);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert multiple rows with a single POST to the Smartsheet API, but all the rows in that call will be added at the same heirachal level in your sheet. So, to create a sheet using rows with parent/children relationships you could do the following:

First, make one call to insert all the parent level rows into your sheet.

Then, using the rowIds of the newly created rows, make additional calls to POST all the children rows for each parent.  You'll need to make a separate call for each parent row's group of children rows.

Comment: Wish I could at least POST all the childrens of various parents at once, with each row containing it's parent.
With this I'll have to make 2 Utilities.sleep(1000*60) because of the 300 calls per minute, it won't be fast, but will work.

Comment: @Kriggs - Not sure how you are implementing it, but I'd recommend being reactive to the rate limit error with exponential back-off, instead of proactively waiting when you think you have hit the limit. The 300 calls/min is a worst-case scenario. The effective rate limit is likely higher. Also, it is a rolling request count, using the total number of hits in the last 60 seconds instead of a throttling window, i.e. you hit the max, now you must wait 60 seconds. Hope that helps.

Comment: stmcallister - Got it to work, lot's of head bashing but will save us alot of time of indenting now, as a sugestion, when importing a sheet, there could be a selection of a column which will designated parents. @kyanskeem - actuallly didn't hit the calls/min limit, since the whole execution transcript takes 200+ seconds, every call takes no less than 0.3s, and some takes up 1.5s, so there's no way I could use up 300 in 60 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the original questions was no, but did as stmcallister answered, it's not pretty nor fast, but works.

```
function preencherSmartSheet(){
  var v_sheetId = ##########; //Id planilha, definida no cronograma
  var dadosOrc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Orçamento").getRange("A3:K").getValues();
  var rows = [], v_maxNivel = 0, v_linhasIds = [], calls = 0, payload, tempId;

  //Enviado ao smartsheet
  var dadosEnviar = accessToken; // Definido na aba Smartsheet API.gs
  dadosEnviar.Method = "post"; //post = incluir

  //Pega os dados da planilha Smartsheet
  var planilhaSmart = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.smartsheet.com/1.1/sheet/"+v_sheetId, accessToken));
  calls++;

  //Verifica qual a coluna das tarefas
  var idColuna = [];
  for(i in planilhaSmart.columns){
    if(planilhaSmart.columns[i].title == "Nome da tarefa"){
      idColuna[1] = planilhaSmart.columns[i].id;
    }else if(planilhaSmart.columns[i].title == "n°"){
      idColuna[0] = planilhaSmart.columns[i].id;
    }
  }

  //verifica maior nivel para começar
  for(i in dadosOrc){
    if(dadosOrc[i][10] > v_maxNivel){
      v_maxNivel = dadosOrc[i][10];
    }
  }

  //Formata as linhas em Objeto JSON
  for(v_nivelAtual = v_maxNivel; v_nivelAtual >= 0; v_nivelAtual--){
    for(i = 0; i < dadosOrc.length; i++){
      if(dadosOrc[i][10] == v_nivelAtual){
        if(v_nivelAtual == v_maxNivel){
          for(; i < dadosOrc.length; i++){
            if(dadosOrc[i][10] == v_nivelAtual){
              rows.push({"cells":[{"columnId" : idColuna[0].toString(), "strict" : false, "value" : i},
                                  {"columnId" : idColuna[1].toString(), "strict" : true, "value" : dadosOrc[i][0].toString()}]});
            }
          }
        }else{
          rows = [];
          tempId = i;
          for(; i < dadosOrc.length && dadosOrc[i][10] <= v_nivelAtual; i++){
            if(dadosOrc[i][10] == v_nivelAtual){
              rows.push({"cells":[{"columnId" : idColuna[0].toString(), "strict" : false, "value" : i},
                                  {"columnId" : idColuna[1].toString(), "strict" : true, "value" : dadosOrc[i][0].toString()}]});
            }
          }
        }

        if(v_nivelAtual < v_maxNivel){
          payload = {"toBottom":true, "rows":rows, "parentId" :  dadosOrc[tempId][1].toString()};
        }else{
          payload = {"toBottom":true, "rows":rows};
        }

        dadosEnviar.payload = JSON.stringify(payload);

        UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.smartsheet.com/1.1/sheet/"+v_sheetId+"/rows", dadosEnviar);
        calls++;
      }
    }


    planilhaSmart = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.smartsheet.com/1.1/sheet/"+v_sheetId, {headers:cabecalhoSmartsheet}));
    calls++;

    //Array com os id's da linhas pais, indice do array = linha do pai
    for(i in planilhaSmart.rows){
      v_linhasIds[planilhaSmart.rows[i].cells[0].value] = planilhaSmart.rows[i].id;
    }

    //Coloca no item 1 do array de dados do orçamento o id da linha pai das mesmas
    for(i in dadosOrc){
      if((dadosOrc[i][10]*1) == ((v_nivelAtual*1) - 1)){
        for(ii = i; ii >= 0; ii--){
          if(v_linhasIds[ii]){
            dadosOrc[i][1] = v_linhasIds[ii]
            ii = 0;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  Logger.log(calls);
}
```