# How can I call to Smartsheet API using Google Apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, smartsheet-api

I have used Postman and Charles to see if my Smartsheet GET function works, and all is well, I get the data json string back.

I have tried running the call from local code and from a Google app script html page.

But I get this error from the Google app script page:

"XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/ MY SMART SHEET ID. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://n-n662xy6uqbadudjpoghatx4igmurid667k365ni-script.googleusercontent.com' is therefore not allowed access."

It is my aim to update a Google sheet automatically from a Smartsheet sheet.

My Ajax request looks like this:

```
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/SHEET_ID",
  "method": "GET",
  "headers": {
    "authorization": "Bearer MY_SECRET_ACCESS_TOKEN",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "postman-token": "SOME_LONG_TOKEN"
  }
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You **cannot** call the Smartsheet API from client-side JavaScript due to the fact that the API doesn't support [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) at this time.

You **can** call the Smartsheet API directly from a Google Apps Script. In fact, we/Smartsheet publish two Google Add-ons that both use the Smartsheet API from scripts ([1](https://www.smartsheet.com/apps/google-docs-smartsheet-merge),[2](https://www.smartsheet.com/apps/google-forms-smartsheet-sync)).

The [Google apps-script-oauth2 project](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2) provides a complete example of using the Smartsheet API in their sample directory on GitHub. See [samples/Smartsheet.gs](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2/blob/master/samples/Smartsheet.gs).

With the OAuth token out of the way, you can make requests to the Smartsheet API like so:

```
var url = 'https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/users/me';
var options = {
  'method': 'get'
  , 'headers': {"Authorization": "Bearer " + getSmartsheetService().getAccessToken()  }
};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getContentText();
Logger.log("email:" + JSON.parse(response).email);
```

Note that `getSmartsheetService()` in the above example is just like `getDriveService()` in Google's Readme except for Smartsheet. The full code is below:

```
function getSmartsheetService() {
    // Create a new service with the given name. The name will be used when
    // persisting the authorized token, so ensure it is unique within the
    // scope of the property store.
    return OAuth2.createService('scott_smartsheet')

        // Set the endpoint URLs, which are the same for all Google services.
        .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://app.smartsheet.com/b/authorize')
        .setTokenUrl('https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/token')

        // Set the client ID and secret, from the Google Developers Console.
        .setClientId(SMARTSHEET_CLIENT_ID)
        .setClientSecret(SMARTSHEET_CLIENT_SECRET)

        // Set the name of the callback function in the script referenced
        // above that should be invoked to complete the OAuth flow.
        .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')

        // Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
        .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())

        // Set the scopes to request (space-separated for Google services).
        .setScope('READ_SHEETS')

        // Set the handler for adding Smartsheet's required SHA hash parameter to the payload:
        .setTokenPayloadHandler(smartsheetTokenHandler)
        ;
}
```

Comment: I can use the fetchURL method mentioned by Mr.Robot. But the response only contains a limited amount of data from the smartsheet that I am accessing, why is that? 

'function callSmartSheet(){

var params = {
"headers": {
    "authorization": "Bearer <secret code>",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",   
  },
    "method": "GET",
}
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/<secret code>/", params);

   var responseCode = response.getResponseCode();
   if (responseCode === 200){
   Logger.log(response);
   } else {
   Logger.log(responseCode); 
   }   
 }'

Comment: What data are you missing? See the include parameter of the API docs for getSheet at http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?shell#get-sheet for information on how to make sure the information you want is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Under external APIs under [Google Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external#connecting_to_public_apis),

> Google Apps Script can interact with APIs from all over the web.
>
> *Connecting to public APIs*
>
> Dozens of Google APIs are available in Apps Script, either as built-in services or advanced services. If you want to use a Google (or non-Google) API that isn't available as an Apps Script service, you can connect to the API's public HTTP interface through the URL Fetch service.

The following example makes a request to the YouTube API and returns a feed of videos that match the query `skateboarding dog`.

```
var url = 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?'
+ 'q=skateboarding+dog'
+ '&start-index=21'
+ '&max-results=10'
+ '&v=2';
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
Logger.log(response);
```

Here is a related [SO ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25294847/setting-a-batch-of-parents-sibblings-in-one-call) that connected his code in google apps script to smartsheet api.